# Kotlin Unchecked cast: Any? to Map(String, String> explanation?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and was wondering if someone could explain this warning and how to correct it?

The below snippet causes the "as Map" text to show as highlighted in Android Studio with the message:

*Unchecked cast: Any? to Map(String, String>*

The suggested fix tell me to make it generic and use `<*, *>` in place of `<String, String>`.

However, if that is done then the val is not the correct type.

In any case, I have this in various spots of the code.  It does not seem to cause a problem and the code functions, but I am concerned I may need to correct this before release.

Any help and explanation would be very help.

```kotlin
DBManager.sharedInstance.getAvailability(mMarkerData.mMarkerUser!!) { avail ->
    val availability = avail as Availability
    val availabilityChoices = availability["availabilityChoices"] as Map<String, String>

    .
    .
    .
}
```

UPDATE:

The `getAvailability` fun is defined as follows:

```
fun getAvailability(user: ParseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(), success: (Availability) -> Unit)
```

availabilityChoices is defined in a model class as follows:

```
var availabilityChoices by ParseDelegate<Map<String, String>>()
```

Comment: What's the type of availability["availabilityChoices"] ?

Comment: If you are sure it is of type `Map<String, String>` then its all fine, you can just supress the warning. It comes because of erased generic (type erasure) of JVM. Basically the types are unknown at runtime so it cannot be checked what it holds.

Comment: I have updated the post to show the call to getAvailability:   fun getAvailability(user: ParseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(), success: (Availability) -> Unit)

Comment: Animesh, thank you for the explanation.  I thought it may be something like this, but I wanted to be sure. Thank you for the response.